# Can not ALTER or DROP a big Imapa partitionned tables - CAUSED BY: MetaException: Timeout when executing

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, impala, metastore

I have a several **impala partitionned tables** that have more than 50k partitions, it work a good except the Hive Metastore operations, like `DROP` and `ALTER` ... `RENAME`, I face this error message:

> **Query:** drop table cars
>
> **ERROR:** ImpalaRuntimeException: Error making 'dropTable' RPC to Hive Metastore: 
>       CAUSED BY: MetaException: Timeout when executing method: drop_table_with_environment_context; 600003ms exceeds 600000ms

I don't know if it's a memory problem? or it's normal and I should adjust the timeout value.. ? if yes, which one ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it External Table or Internal Table?

Comment: It might be due to Permission issue.

Comment: @SurendranathaReddyChappidi, it's a internal table.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `CASCADE`. If your table has partitions,
the query should be

```
DROP TABLE CARS CASCADE;
```

Comment: Now that it has been edited, this is an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to hive metastore. You could try directly connecting to hms and see if dropping partitions works there, and you'll get more information of why it doesn't work.